# Memory leak detection and cycles

Tags: android, delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-10.1-berlin

I tried to use a cross platform memory leak detection code from https://bitbucket.org/shadow_cs/.

I wrote a small Android demo app containing a cycle:

```
type
  TMyClassA = class(TObject)
  public
    Other : TMyClassA;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b: TMyClassA;
begin
  a := TMyClassA.Create;
  b := TMyClassA.Create;

  a.Other := b;
  b.Other := a;
end;
```

And then I run it on Android (added the needed units to the project, library paths, etc).

When I press the button and quit the application, I can see tons of messages about something leaking in logcat, but it seems to never end.

Is this due to my cycle?

If yes, what do I need to do, and why doesn't it show the name of the objects leaked but only their addresses?

Excerpt from logcat:

```
05-25 21:00:14.257: W/leak(8382): Leak detected CC4BC740 size 48 B
05-25 21:00:14.266: W/leak(8382):   01 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.302: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.334: W/leak(8382): Leak detected CC4BCEC0 size 48 B
05-25 21:00:14.366: W/leak(8382):   01 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.400: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.425: W/leak(8382): Leak detected CC4B1E40 size 256 B
05-25 21:00:14.467: W/leak(8382):   40 AD 6B CA C0 0F 4C CC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | @?k???L?????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.503: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 12 4C CC 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????H?L?????
05-25 21:00:14.543: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 1C 4C CC C8 14 4C CC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????H?L???L?????????
05-25 21:00:14.573: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.605: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.639: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.674: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
05-25 21:00:14.708: W/leak(8382):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ????????????????????????????????
```

The project of the leak detection is hosted on Bitbucket. I'm new to that one, but unlike GitHub I don't see any way to contact the authors. Otherwise I'd have asked them first.

Comment: Variable names don't exist at runtime, that is why the leak log can only report addresses. You should log the addresses of your objects when you create them so you know which leak corresponds to which object name. It is clear from your log that you have more than just the 2 leaks that your example is creating.

Comment: Thanks Remy in the first place for the editing and your comment. About the adr

Comment: About the addresses: I'm accustomed to the FastMM4 leak reports on Win32 which do tell me the class names of the objects leaked, so my question was a little bit wrong: I didn't mean the variable names but the class names. Another issue: if my project is leaking more than these 2 instances my code excerpt shows, then FMX apps have some serious problem. I had just created a blank multi device app, added that button I show in my question and the code I show in my question. Nothing more.

Comment: I asked about another issue with it now here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544275/how-to-get-stack-trace-working-in-delphis-shadow-cs-library

Comment: Reading the readme file again and thus adding  TLeakCheck.IgnoredLeakTypes := [tkUnknown]; removes most leaks and I do get proper class names now.

Comment: Git commits always have an email address ;)

Comment: @StefanGlienke Good luck trying to contact me through mine ;)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I know that you can put anything there but I know that the one in question here will reach the author of LeakCheck :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint about e-mail address given in Git commits. I contacted the author now about some points, e.g. the toolchain path in compile.bat is wrong at least for NDK r10e and I suggested I might write a little commandline utility which can (when the NDK installation path is given as parameter) automatically create the compile.bat file (based on some template). it would simply search for a suitable GCC.exe and thus detect the valid path to it no matter which NDK version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is due to the cycles. In order to prevent those leaks you have to either manually unassign them or use `[Weak]` attribute so the compiler/RTL knows about possible cycles and the reference count is not incremented when assigning to weak fields, instead it "remembers" the assignment and unassigns the field when the objects is freed (so you won't access freed instance but still get an nil-pointer AV when you get in that scenario). Another option is to use `[Unsafe]` (or assign/unassign your instance as `Pointer(fField) := instance`) which inhibits ARC and Weak references altogether.

LeakCheck reports all memory leaks but only some types contain additional information so type can be iknferred (LeakCheck supports strings/objects), so you were right to ignore those unknowns.

LeakCheck does implement cycle detection and outputs it in Graphviz DOT format so it can be visualized. I'd recommend using file logging (add `LeakCheck.Report.FileLog` to your project AFTER `LeakCheck`) it will output the leaks and graph to separate files (keep in mind the destination folder `/storage/emulated/0/` needs to be accessible by the app) so it is easier to transfer for processing than logcat output. Refer to `CustomLeakReportFMX` sample for more details.